# Evenly distributed points on spline using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, spline

I'm using numpy to generate a spline based on b-spline parameters. These parameters have been read from a STEP file exported from CAD with the end goal being to write a 2D unstructured mesh generator. I need to generate evenly spaced points on the spline to act as vertexes for the mesh elements.

Annoyingly, however, numpy is generating highly unevenly distributed points along the spline and I'm not sure why.

Here is an example of an [aerofoil b-spline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8tJT.png) - the control points are relatively evenly placed around the spline and there is sufficient resolution in the spline coordinates.
But when I evaluate the same [spline with 10x less points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUjSZ.png), you can see the distribution is heavily weighted to the upper line.

This is the code I'm using to generate the points (the bspline parameters have already been defined according to the STEP file):

```py
N=int(ctrl_pts.shape[0]*100)    # number of points to evaluate
spline_range=np.linspace(
    knot_vector[0],
    knot_vector[-1],
    N
)

bspline=numpy.interpolate.BSpline(knot_vector,ctrl_pts,degree)
points=bspline(spline_range)
```

Is there a way to 'redistribute' the points on the spline?

Comment: So you want the arc length, by the sound of it

Comment: @ev-br I want to redistribute the points along the arc length so that each point is spaced evenly from the next. Calculating the arc length isn't a problem - I'm doing it by evaluating the spline for a higher resolution of points than needed and summing the distance between each.